# Jenkins shell not working from within Seed DSL generated Job

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

new to Groovy, Closures & Jenkins.

I have created a seed job:

```
def Job1 = 'FromTemplate-testJob'
job {
    name Job1
    steps {
       shell( "echo Hello > out5.txt" )
       shell( "/c echo custard > op4.txt")
    }
}
```

which as expected successfully creates a sub-job containing the 2 shell commands:

```
echo Hello > out5.txt
/c echo custard > op4.txt
```

However, when run, this created job apparently runs successfully with the following output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\FromTemplate-testJob\workspace
[workspace] $ C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson3852539874278383422.sh
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\FromTemplate-testJob\workspace>[workspace] $ C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson1697067517687695305.sh
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\FromTemplate-testJob\workspace>Finished: SUCCESS
```

However neither of the output files are not created anywhere. The shell executable is defined as:

```
 C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

What don't I understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`shell`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference#shell-command) dsl command is translated to "Execute shell" build step, which usually is used on Unix-like systems. You have to use [batchFile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference#batch-file) dsl command instead, so it will be translated to "Execute Windows batch command" build step, which is used for Windows:

```
def Job1 = 'FromTemplate-testJob'
job {
    name Job1
    steps {
        batchFile( "echo Hello > out5.txt" )
        batchFile( "echo custard > op4.txt" )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back so quickly, however once changed to batchFile I get the following compile error from the seed DSL - ERROR: Build step failed with exception
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.StepHelper.batchFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [echo Hello > out5.txt]

Comment: Looks strange. It works well for me with latest DSL plugin (1.35). Did you just copy and paste it ?

Comment: Just replaced the "steps { ... }" section

and now getting a list of errors longer than the average elephant's trunk.

Comment: Which version of dsl plugin are you using ?

Comment: I'm using  Job DSL 1.35 1.0-beta

Comment: Probably you are using [outdated](https://github.com/JavaPosseRoundup/job-dsl-plugin) dsl plugin. Could you try to install using Jenkins Plugin Center ?

Comment: Yes that has now fixed the problem - Just moved to job-dsl plugin 1.35. Appreciated.

Comment: Great! Does this fully resolve your problem ? Files created ?

Comment: Yes it fully resolves the problem, files created & Sanity has returned! thanks.

Comment: sorry I thought I had. I clicked the Orange triangle, is there any more I can do?

Comment: When you click the orange triangle, you vote up. But you can also [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). That means that your problem is solved